# Tensorflow - apply function over 1D Tensor

Tags: tensorflow

I have a function `dice`

```
def dice(yPred,yTruth,thresh):
    smooth = tf.constant(1.0)
    threshold = tf.constant(thresh)
    yPredThresh = tf.to_float(tf.greater_equal(yPred,threshold))
    mul = tf.mul(yPredThresh,yTruth)
    intersection = 2*tf.reduce_sum(mul) + smooth
    union = tf.reduce_sum(yPredThresh) + tf.reduce_sum(yTruth) + smooth
    dice = intersection/union
    return dice, yPredThresh
```

which works. An example is given here

```
with tf.Session() as sess:

    thresh = 0.5 
    print("Dice example")
    yPred = tf.constant([0.1,0.9,0.7,0.3,0.1,0.1,0.9,0.9,0.1],shape=[3,3])
    yTruth = tf.constant([0.0,1.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,1.0,1.0],shape=[3,3])
    diceScore, yPredThresh= dice(yPred=yPred,yTruth=yTruth,thresh= thresh)

    diceScore_ , yPredThresh_ , yPred_, yTruth_ = sess.run([diceScore,yPredThresh,yPred, yTruth])
    print("\nScore = {0}".format(diceScore_))
```

`>>> Score = 0.899999976158`

I would like to be able to loop over the third arguement of dice, thresh. I do not know the best way to do this such that I can extract it from the graph. Something along the lines of the following...

```
def diceROC(yPred,yTruth,thresholds=np.linspace(0.1,0.9,20)):
    thresholds = thresholds.astype(np.float32)
    nThreshs = thresholds.size
    diceScores = tf.zeros(shape=nThreshs)

    for i in xrange(nThreshs):
        score,_ = dice(yPred,yTruth,thresholds[i])
        diceScores[i] = score
    return diceScores
```

Evaluating `diceScoreROC` yields the error `'Tensor' object does not support item assignment` as I can't loop into and slice a tf tensor apparently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of the loop, I would encourage you to use broadcasting abilities of tensorflow. If you redefine `dice` to:

```
def dice(yPred,yTruth,thresh):
    smooth = tf.constant(1.0)
    yPredThresh = tf.to_float(tf.greater_equal(yPred,thresh))
    mul = tf.mul(yPredThresh,yTruth)
    intersection = 2*tf.reduce_sum(mul, [0, 1]) + smooth
    union = tf.reduce_sum(yPredThresh, [0, 1]) + tf.reduce_sum(yTruth, [0, 1]) + smooth
    dice = intersection/union
    return dice, yPredThresh
```

You will be able to pass 3-dimensional `yPred` and `yTruth` (assuming the tensors will be just repeated along the last dimension) and 1-dimensional `thresh`:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:

    thresh = [0.1,0.9,20, 0.5]
    print("Dice example")
    yPred = tf.constant([0.1,0.9,0.7,0.3,0.1,0.1,0.9,0.9,0.1],shape=[3,3,1])
    ypred_tiled = tf.tile(yPred, [1,1,4])
    yTruth = tf.constant([0.0,1.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,1.0,1.0],shape=[3,3,1])
    ytruth_tiled = tf.tile(yTruth, [1,1,4])
    diceScore, yPredThresh= dice(yPred=ypred_tiled,yTruth=ytruth_tiled,thresh= thresh)

    diceScore_ = sess.run(diceScore)
    print("\nScore = {0}".format(diceScore_))
```

You'll get:

```
Score = [ 0.73333335  0.77777779  0.16666667  0.89999998]
```